# Rust assignment and use borrow at the same time

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

It confuses me that the error at line `A` has anything to do with line `C`, as they basically appear in different branches?

```rust
pub struct ListNode {
    pub val: i32,
    pub next: Option<Box<ListNode>>
}

pub fn foo(mut head: Option<Box<ListNode>>) -> Option<Box<ListNode>> {
    let mut p1 = head.as_mut()?;
    
    if let Some(p2) = p1.next.as_mut() {
        if true {
            p1.next = None; // A: Error here if C is not commented out 
        } else {
            // p1.next = None; // B
            p1 = p2; // C: No error on this line
        }
    }
    head
```

To make things worse, the error has code E0506, suggesting an attempt is made to assign a borrowed value (`p1.next`). How come I cannot assign this borrowed value (which I believe is mutably borrowed) now but I *can* do that simply by deleting line `C`?

```rust
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `p1.next` because it is borrowed
  --> src/remove_dup.rs:11:13
   |
9  |     if let Some(p2) = p1.next.as_mut() {
   |                       ------- borrow of `p1.next` occurs here
10 |         if true {
11 |             p1.next = None; // A: Error happnens here if C is not commented out 
   |             ^^^^^^^
   |             |
   |             assignment to borrowed `p1.next` occurs here
   |             borrow later used here
```

Comment: There's an error assigning to `p1.next` because p1 is borrowed by the `if let` and therefore cannot be accessed while `p2` is in scope.  If you move the `if let` to be inside the else, the code will compile.  That said, you probably don't want to be doing a linked list like this in rust.  It's probably best to use Vec or VecDequeue, but more info can be found [here](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/index.html)

Comment: I was completing all of the Rust exercises on exercism.io with no problem at all until I hit the linked list exercise, and then came so unstuck that I abandoned Rust for months. There's really no good way to implement a linked list in Rust without using `unsafe` code sections, so this is probably not a suitable challenge for anyone getting started in Rust.

Comment: @Bobulous If you're still interested in creating a linked list in Rust, or possibly multiple linked lists in Rust, there's a online book called Learn Rust with Entirely Too Many Linked Lists: https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/